# Integration testing of ansible playbooks on a physical server

Tags: linux, ansible, testing

I would like to be able to test my ansible playbooks. Currently I have no testing in place for these playbooks. I was looking at molecule as a possibility, however this relies on creating docker containers. Since my playbooks use information about the computer e.g specific CPU, Chipsets etc), this is a no go.
I did notice that molecule supports vagrant which may be a possible solution, but it is not officially supported anymore.

Ideally, I would lie to test the scripts on "bare metal" ( a physical server). I have a server available to me. Is there a package or tool that I could use?

Comment: Why can't you use docker containers? Inside of a docker container, you have information about the CPU etc. of the host system available.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider using a VM with a snapshot you can quickly restore.

Comment: Yes, use a VM. Or multiple VMs.  From the point of view of software like Ansible, there's little or no difference between a virtual machine and a physical machine.  qemu and virsh both offer several variants for motherboards, graphics, and other hardware - not exactly the same as on physical hardware but enough variety that you can test different behaviours for different "HW".